# IOS resizing labels

Tags: ios, lists, iphone, labels, resizing

So I'm wondering how best to solve this problem.

I want to display a 'list' of elements in my app. Right now this is what it looks like -

[image]

That looks really bad, and I'm not sure how to make it so that there's some consistency to the look of the elements on this page.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It's because your labels autosize the text to try and display the whole thing. I think it's fine provided most titles fit within a standard range of sizes.

Comment: yes - but I don't have a standard range of sizes...so I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to break the longest labels into two lines and change their font size. I'd suggest to rework the label's phrases if they are way too long. Otherwise, you can try to break them up to three lines (reducing the font size / increasing the block's height).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8uO8n.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @praks5432 how would you code this ? Don't really understand what's the question ^^